# Copying raster to SQLite using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, sql, ogr, spatial-database

I want to copy a raster file into SQLite database. Previously, I did the same with vector data like this:

```
def store_vector_output(self, file_name, identifier):
    from osgeo import ogr
    drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("SQLite")
    dsc_out = drv.CreateDataSource(self.dblocation)
    layer = dsc_out.CopyLayer(dsc_in.GetLayer(), identifier,
                              ['OVERWRITE=YES'])

    dsc_out.Destroy()
    dsc_in.Destroy()
```

With raster data, I expected it to be similar:

```
def store_raster_output(self, file_name, identifier):
    from osgeo import gdal

    dsc_in = gdal.Open(file_name)
    drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("SQLite")
    dsc_out = drv.Create(self.dblocation, xsize=30, ysize=30)
    layer = dsc_out.CopyLayer(dsc_in.GetLayer(), identifier,
                              ['OVERWRITE=YES'])

    dsc_out.Destroy()
    dsc_in.Destroy()
```

However, in store_raster_output, `dsc_in.GetLayer()` is `None`. There are no layers in `dsc_in` (its datatype is `<class 'osgeo.gdal.Dataset'>`)

So, I tried to use `dsc_in.CreateLayer("some_name")` but that resulted in this:

`ERROR 6: CreateLayer() not supported by this dataset.`

Therer is also a method `ReadRaster()` but since I am using `CopyLayer` the argument must be of datatype layer.

How do I write a raster file to SQLite?

Perhaps using a different command than CopyLayer?

I didn't find any such command [here](http://gdal.org/python/) but maybe I just didn't know where to look.

Comment: The raster driver of the SpatiaLite family is "rasterlite". Find examples from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/rasterlite.py. GeoPackege raster could be a better choise at the moment, rasterlite is under development and unstable.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't entirely understand what you are suggesting. I don't explicitly use RasterLite, or do I? If I am to use GeoPackage instead, where do I say so? Could you please explain it a little bit more in detail?

Comment: SQLite driver is a vector driver and you can't use it for rasters. Select some raster driver that stores data into SQlite: rasterlite, gpkg, or mbtiles.

Answer (score 0):

Use gdal_translate to create an mbtiles (tns),or gpkg  (XYZ) tiles then use gdaladdo to add ZOOM LEVELS. Or use gdal2tiles_parallel and mbutil

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with GDAL Compiled binaries (.exe) no python. Just have binaries somewhere and open a CMD there and write command.

CMD for translate to Spatialite:

```
"C:\path\to\gdal_translate_exe\gdal_translate" -of Rasterlite C:\job\data\MNT_Ombre_32E03SO.tif C:/job/data/test.sqlite"
```

Example CMD to translate in Geopackage:

```
"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal_translate" -of GPKG MNT.tif test.gpkg -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=MNT_TEST
```

GDAL binaries can come with OSGEO install: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki
or can be find here http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php